# iOS Push Notification Redirect to View when App becomes Active

Tags: ios, ios5, apple-push-notifications

Is there any way to redirect to a View once the user opens the App from the Notification Center considering that the App was just launched before the action. (App is still running in the background)

Example, I launch the App normally, press the home button. Then I received a number of remote notifications, and then I open the app anywhere from that push notification.

Since I have different push notifications that could redirect to any part of my App. I want that the redirect would still work not only in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

is it possible that I could still access the remote notification (json data within) during application becomes active? so that I could do some redirection. And also, so that the user can just run through the remote notifications he have in the center, and will be redirected to the proper view depending on what notification the user tapped.

**Update**

Another Example:
 
(1)User receives the 2 push notifications in `application: didReceiveRemoteNotification:` 
(2)User is redirected with the first push notification.
 (3)User goes to his notification center
 (4)taps the other notification. Will he still be redirected? I don't think the app won't go inside in either `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` or `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can, here is a simple outline/sample

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
 {
      //When notification is pressed on background it will enter here

      //Get strings based on information on your json payload for example
      if([[userInfo objectForKey:@"keyword"] isEqualToString:@"value"]){
           //redirect/push a screen here for example
      }
 }
```

Comment: btw thanks, :) I updated my question for another example scenario

Comment: for your updated question, Yes he still will be redirected and the app will enter. application:didReceiveRemoteNotification (it always enters application:didReceiveRemoteNotification if you click a notification)

Comment: yeah, it works, I thought it only works when the user taps on it immediately

Answer (score 4):

There is User info associated with DIDReceiveRemoteNotification Method... You can use it following delegate method.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSDictionary* userInfo =
        [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (userInfo) {
        [self processRemoteNotification:userInfo];
    }
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [self processRemoteNotification:userInfo];
}
```

After that in user info there is key called APS and you can use that with following method.

```
NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
```

After that you can get every element from the pay load of APNS and decide which view to redirect to.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but, will this work, example. (1)User receives the 2 push notifications in application: didReceiveRemoteNotification: (2)User is redirected with the first push notification. (3)User goes to his notification center (4)taps the other notification. Will he still be redirected? I don't think the app won't go inside in either application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: or application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could.

The following delegate method will be called once you receive the remote notification.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo;
```

Comment: thanks, btw thanks, :) I updated my question for another example scenario, :)